# Uneable to find TransformToGrayscaleOp class in android for transform to greyscale in android

Tags: android, image, kotlin, image-processing, tensorflow-lite

I want to transform my image to grayscale but when i traid to use [TransformToGrayscaleOp](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/java/org/tensorflow/lite/support/image/ops/TransformToGrayscaleOp?hl=en) class i got this error in the ide: `Unresolved reference: TransformToGrayscaleOp`

Here's my code until now:

```
val model = Modelo.newInstance(applicationContext)
        val imageProcessor: ImageProcessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
            .add(ResizeOp(150, 150, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
            .add( TransformToGrayscaleOp()) //<-----
            .build()
        imageProcessor.process(tensorImage)
        model.process(tensorImage.tensorBuffer)
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.8.0'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0'
```

Why i dont have that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your tensorflow-lite-support library

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.3.1'
```